# GPR project where every source file is a main file?

Tags: ada, gnat

I have the following project structure, where every `.adb` file is a standalone executable that *does not and will not depend on anything else*:

```
project/
├── project.gpr
├── bin/
│   ├── bar
│   ├── baz
│   └── foo
├── obj/
│   └── .o's, .ali's, etcetera
└── src/
    ├── bar.adb
    ├── baz.adb
    └── foo.adb
```

And this is `project.gpr`:

```
project Project is
   for Source_Dirs use ("src");
   for Object_Dir use "obj";
   for Exec_Dir use "bin";
   for Main use ("src/foo.adb", "src/bar.adb", "src/baz.adb");
end Project;
```

Currently `gprbuild` and `gprclean` do exactly what I want, however the number of files under `src/` might grow into the hundreds.

Is there a way to tell GPRbuild that every `.adb` file under `src/` shall be considered a `Main` target without explicitly listing each one of them?

Comment: The [documentation](http://docs.adacore.com/live/wave/gprbuild/html/gprbuild_ug/gprbuild_ug/gnat_project_manager.html#main-subprograms) says you’re not supposed to put the directory component in main file names (not an answer, I know, but ..)

Comment: Appreciated all the same, I'm just starting to learn the ropes of Ada.

Comment: Since you're starting out with Ada, you should keep in mind that Ada is a programming language and GNAT is a specific compiler for that language. Details of how GNAT performs that compilation, including its project mechanism, project-file language, pressure to use specific file names, pressure to have only a single compilation unit per file, and the like, are technically not Ada. You should try to keep separate in your mind which parts of what you're learning are Ada and which are GNAT-specific.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using GPR, you may consider the use of aggregate projects.

You define 1 GPR per executable to be produced.
Then you define 1 aggregate GPR to build them all.

I do believe you are very close to a use case described [in this link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.1/gnat_ugn_unw/Building-all-main-programs-from-a-single-project-tree.html#Building-all-main-programs-from-a-single-project-tree)

Quoting:

> Most often, an application is organized into modules and submodules, which are very conveniently represented as a project tree or graph (the root project A withs the projects for each modules (say B and C), which in turn with projects for submodules.
>
> Very often, modules will build their own executables (for testing purposes for instance), or libraries (for easier reuse in various contexts).
>
> However, if you build your project through gnatmake or gprbuild, using a syntax similar to

```
    gprbuild -PA.gpr
```

> this will only rebuild the main programs of project A, not those of the imported projects B and C. Therefore you have to spawn several gnatmake commands, one per project, to build all executables. This is a little inconvenient, but more importantly is inefficient because gnatmake needs to do duplicate work to ensure that sources are up-to-date, and cannot easily compile things in parallel when using the -j switch.
>
> Also libraries are always rebuilt when building a project.
>
> You could therefore define an aggregate project Agg that groups A, B and C. Then, when you build with

```
     gprbuild -PAgg.gpr
```

> this will build all mains from A, B and C.

```
    aggregate project Agg is
       for Project_Files use ("a.gpr", "b.gpr", "c.gpr");
    end Agg;
```

Of course, you end up having a little overhead of creating 1 GPR for each main, but it seems rather logic to clearly define each built artefact, specially if they will

> never depend on each other

as you stated in your question.

However, it seems that GPR accepts a syntax for GPR aggregates where all GPRs in a given directory are taken into account. see [here](https://docs.adacore.com/gprbuild-docs/html/gprbuild_ug/gnat_project_manager.html#building-all-main-programs-from-a-single-project-closure), and specifically [here](https://docs.adacore.com/gprbuild-docs/html/gprbuild_ug/gnat_project_manager.html#syntax-of-aggregate-projects)

> Project_Files:
>
> This attribute is compulsory. It specifies a list of constituent .gpr files that are grouped in the aggregate. The list may be empty. The project files can be any projects except configuration or abstract projects; they can be other aggregate projects. When grouping standard projects, you can have both the root of a project import closure (and you do not need to specify all its imported projects), and any project within the closure.
>
> The basic idea is to specify all those projects that have main programs you want to build and link, or libraries you want to build. You can specify projects that do not use the Main attribute or the `Library_*` attributes, and the result will be to build all their source files (not just the ones needed by other projects).
>
> [...]
>
> Paths can also include the `*` and `**` globbing patterns. The latter indicates that any subdirectory (recursively) will be searched for matching files. The `**` pattern can only occur at the last position in the directory part (i.e. `a/**/*.gpr` is supported, but not `**/a/*.gpr`). Starting the pattern with `**` is equivalent to starting with `./**`.
>
> At present the pattern `*` is only allowed in the filename part, not in the directory part. This is mostly for efficiency reasons to limit the number of system calls that are needed.
>
> Here are a few examples:

```
    for Project_Files use ("a.gpr", "subdir/b.gpr");
    --  two specific projects relative to the directory of agg.gpr

    for Project_Files use ("/.gpr");
    --  all projects recursively
```

Comment: I may misunderstand this, but doesn't this just move the burden of specifying every main file in the GPR to specifying every GPR in the aggregate GPR?  Or is the example just doing that and there is an alternate syntax where you don't have to manually specify every GPR in the aggregate?

Comment: Answer edited accordingly: it seems possible to avoid the pain of specifying each .gpr file.